# Trying to design Core Data Model for an Audio playing app in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a question about Core Data modelling that I wanted to ask about.

I'm working on an app that helps users memorize poetry.  This poem is divided as follows:

1. The poem is divided into multiple chapters
2. Each chapter is divided into multiple lines

Now, because of this, I figured I would create two entities as follows:

1. Chapter entity, with the attributes: ChapterNumber, ChapterTitle, and LineEntity.
2. LineEntity, with attributes: ChapterNumber, LineNumber, LineSegment (each line is divided into two parts, a and b), and LineText

Because I plan to have the audio also played for the user, I need a reference to the audio file as well, which is why I figure I need an entity for the AudioFile as well.  Thus I would also have:

3. AudioFile entity, with attributes: ChapterNumber, LineNumber, Start (the point in time when the relevant audio begins), End (the point in time when the relevant audio ends), and possibly fileName.  I have one long file for the entire audio, however, I'm wondering if I should break up the audio file into individual components, where each file represents each line in the poem.  I personally am not sure if this is the right approach.

So my chapter entity would call a collection of Line entities, which in turn, each line object would have a reference to an audio entity.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine that you have one audio file for each poem, and each Line Entity should reference a part of that audio file. I would create that entity "AudioFile", but I would call it "AudioFileSplit" with (as you said)fields: **ReferenceToLineEntity, Start, End.** 
Notice that you dont need the fields ChapterNumber or LineNumber in this entity, since this new entity has already a reference to them(With the line reference you can get the line data, chapter data and poem data).

Now, you need to store the URL of the audio File. Probably you have a entity called "Poem". If you have an audio file for each poem you should add a new field to the poem entity (AudioFileURL maybe?)

Resuming, my Modell would be like

PoemEntity: [Fields For Poem],AudioFileURL, ReferenceToChapters

ChapterEntity:[Fields For Chapter],SingleReferenceToPoem, ReferenceToLines

LineEntity:[Fields For ine], SingleReferenceToChapter, SingleReferenceToAudioFileSplit

AudioFileSplit:SingleReferenceToLine,Start,End

Notice that the relation between LineEntity and AudioFileSplit is 1:1, so you could even simplify it more:

LineEntity:[Fields For Line],SingleReferenceToChapter, Start,End.
(And no AudioFileSplit Entity)

Regards ;)